# Convert const wchar_t* to const char*

Tags: windows, visual-c++

I am trying to use GetHostByName() this requires a const char*. I have my URL in a variable that is in a cost wchar_t* format. How can I convert this so that GetHostByName may use it?  The code.

```
BSTR bstr;
pBrowser->get_LocationURL(&bstr);
std::wstring wsURL;
wsURL = bstr;

size_t DSlashLoc = wsURL.find(L"://");
if (DSlashLoc != wsURL.npos)
    {
    wsURL.erase(wsURL.begin(), wsURL.begin() + DSlashLoc + 3);
    }
DSlashLoc = wsURL.find(L"www.");
if (DSlashLoc == 0)
    {
    wsURL.erase(wsURL.begin(), wsURL.begin() + 4);
    }
DSlashLoc = wsURL.find(L"/");
if (DSlashLoc != wsURL.npos)
    {
    wsURL.erase(DSlashLoc);
    }
    wprintf(L"\n   Current Website URL: %s\n\n", wsURL.c_str());

    HOSTENT *pHostEnt;
    int  **ppaddr;
    SOCKADDR_IN sockAddr;
    char* addr;
    pHostEnt = gethostbyname(wsURL.c_str());
    ppaddr = (int**)pHostEnt->h_addr_list;
    sockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = **ppaddr;
    addr = inet_ntoa(sockAddr.sin_addr);
    printf("\n   Current Website IP:%s", addr);

int length = WideCharToMultiByte (CP_ACP, WC_COMPOSITECHECK, wsURL.c_str(), -1, NULL, 0,  NULL, NULL); 
std::string LogURL(length+1, 0); 
int result = WideCharToMultiByte (CP_ACP, WC_COMPOSITECHECK, wsURL.c_str(), -1, &LogURL[0],length+1,  NULL, NULL);
myfile << "\n   Current Website URL:" << LogURL;
myfile << "\n   Current Website IP:"<< addr;
```

This is the error I am getting.
IntelliSense:argument of type "const wchar_t *" is incompatible with parameter of type "const char *"

Comment: As currently written, you're trying to pass wsURL.c_str() to the gethostbyname function.  Didn't you want to pass LogURL.c_str() instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work. Comments welcome.

```
int Newlength = WideCharToMultiByte (CP_ACP, WC_COMPOSITECHECK, wsURL.c_str(), -1, NULL, 0,  NULL, NULL);
std::string NewLogURL(Newlength+1, 0); 
int Newresult = WideCharToMultiByte (CP_ACP, WC_COMPOSITECHECK, wsURL.c_str(), -1, &NewLogURL[0],Newlength+1,  NULL, NULL);

    HOSTENT *pHostEnt;
    int  **ppaddr;
    SOCKADDR_IN sockAddr;
    char* addr;

    pHostEnt = gethostbyname(NewLogURL.c_str());
    ppaddr = (int**)pHostEnt->h_addr_list;
    sockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = **ppaddr;
    addr = inet_ntoa(sockAddr.sin_addr);
    printf("\n   Current Website IP:%s", addr);
```

Answer (score 5):

I like to use wcstombs() because it is pretty easy to use.

Try this sample:

```
char *str = new char[4046];
wchar_t array[] = L"Hello World";
wcstombs(str, array, 12);
std::cout << str;
```

This is how you have to convert wchar_t into char*.

**EDIT**

Changes in your code:

```
char* addr = new char[4046];
wcstombs(wsURL, addr, wsURL.size());
pHostEnt = gethostbyname(addr);
```

Comment: I'm looking at this and I'm not sure what you mean?  Could you explain further in my context so that I may understand. Thank you.

Comment: @ME:A type that describes a specialization of the template class basic_string with elements of type wchar_t as a wstring.

Comment: @ME:so we can use wcstombs functions to convert wchar_t into const char*.In Edit portion of my Answer,I suggest the solution for your problem.

Comment: This line is causing conversion problems...wcstombs(wsURL, addr, wsURL.length());

Comment: @ME:the third parameter is the length of the wsURL string.so you have to calculate the length and passed that value as the third parameter

Comment: @ME:change the length() function to size().Check the EDIT portion of my answer now.

Comment: The EDIT is wrong.  The params are swapped.  Should be: wcstombs(addr, wsURL, addr.size());

Answer (score 1):

```
    /***** This code is well done *****/

    #include...
    #include...

    int wmain(int argc, wchar_t *argv[])
    {
         ...
         ...
         char *path = new char[255];
         wcstombs(path, argv[2], 255);
         IplImage *img; 
   if (img = cvLoadImage (path, 1))
         {
             Mat input_img = Mat (img);
             imshow ("haha",input_img);
             waitKey(0);
         }
         ...
         ...
         //wcout<<endl<<argv[2];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

WideCharToMultiByte is the Win32 API call that does this at the end of the day, though depending on what frameworks you're using (MFC, WTL, etc), there may be a better way.

Comment: No MFC here.  This is what I have further down in the code and it works.  However when I try to use LogURL I get can't convert std string to const char.    int length = WideCharToMultiByte (CP_ACP, WC_COMPOSITECHECK, wsURL.c_str(), -1, NULL, 0,  NULL, NULL); 
  std::string LogURL(length+1, 0); 
  int result = WideCharToMultiByte (CP_ACP, WC_COMPOSITECHECK, wsURL.c_str(), -1, &LogURL[0],length+1,  NULL, NULL); 
  myfile << "\n   Current Website URL:" << LogURL;
  myfile << "\n   Current Website IP:"<< addr;

Comment: Yee Gads, I'm sorry, having trouble formating this! Look at the question I added it, it's clearer up there.