# Only first character is assigned converting LPCTSTR to char*

Tags: c++, type-conversion

I'm completely new to C++. In my program there's a function which has to take a `LPCTSTR` as a parameter. I want to convert it into a `char*`. What I tried is as follows,

```
char* GetChar(LPCTSTR var){
   char* id = (char*)var;
   .....
}
```

But while debugging I noticed that only first letter of `var` is assigned to `id`.
What have I done wrong?
(I tried various answers in StackOverflow about converting LPCTSTR to char* before coming to this solution. None of them worked for me.)
**UPDATE**
 What i want is to get full string pointed by `var` to be treated as `char*`

Comment: When you say you want to convert "it" into a `char *`, what is the "it"? What are you trying to convert exactly? There is no code to do anything at all to the string `var` points to.

Comment: What makes you think you've assigned anything?  Hint: you can use ",n" in the MSVC debugger or watch windows to see arrays.  Consider looking at "var,10" vs. "id,10".  Second hint: LPCTSTR can contain NUL characters aside from its usual stuff.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I think it's clear. I want to convert LPCTSTR variable into char*.  I can't see any unclear part in it.

Comment: Well then you did exactly that. Why are you expecting anything to happen to the the letters `var` points to? You converted `var`, which is a pointer, into a `char *`. Nothing happened to the string `var` points to. Why are you expecting anything to happen to the letters `var` points to?

Comment: Everything is as expected.

Comment: Ok I get your point. I'm new to pointers and C++. What i wanted is to get full string pointed by `var` to be treated as `char*`.

Comment: @LasithaYapa To do that, you need to allocate some memory and copy the string into it, converting it as you do so.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Can you please add a hint of how to do this, in your answer. I can't understand any solution I find in google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is much more useful to just pick a character set (`wchar_t`, or `char`), and just stick to it, in your application, since trying to use `TCHAR`, when trying to support both, may cause you some headaches. To be fair, today, you can just, safely, use `wchar_t` (or `WCHAR`, since from the current types you are using, I suspect that you are using Windows headers).

The problem that you have, is because casting a pointer does not have any impact on its contents. And, since, *typically* `wchar_t` is 2 bytes in size, while `char` is 1 byte in size, storing the value, that fits inside a `char`, in `wchar_t`, leaves 2nd byte of `wchar_t` set to `\0`. And when you try to print null(`\0`)-terminated string of `wchar_t`s as a string of `char`s, the printing function reaches the `\0` character after reading the first symbol, and assumes it is the end of the string. `\0` character in `wchar_t` is 2 bytes long.

For example, the string

```
LPCWSTR test = L"Hi!";
```

is stored in memory as:

> 48 00 69 00 21 00 00 00

If you want to convert between the `wchar_t` version of the string to `char` version, or vice-versa, there exist some functions, that can do the conversion, and since I noticed that you probably are using Windows headers (from `LPCTSTR` define), those functions are `WideCharToMultiByte`/ `MultiByteToWideChar`.

You may now start to think: *I am not using `wchar_t`! I am using `TCHAR`!*

Typically `TCHAR` is defined in the following way:

```
#ifdef UNICODE
    typedef WCHAR TCHAR;
#else
    typedef char TCHAR;
#endif
```

So you could do similar handling in your  conversion code:

```
template<int N>
bool GetChar(LPCTSTR var, char (&out)[N])){
    #ifdef UNICODE
        return WideCharToMultiByte (CP_ACP, 0, var, -1, out, N, NULL, NULL) != 0;
    #else
        return strcpy_s (out, var) == 0;
    #endif
}
```

Note, the return value of `GetChar` function is `true` if the function Succeeds; `false` - otherwise.

Comment: Oops, forgot that `GetChar` should take array of `char` as an out argument. Trivial mistake :/

Answer (score 1):

You code has told the compiler to convert `var` (which is a pointer) into a pointer to a character and then assign that converted value to `id`. The only thing it converts is the pointer value. It doesn't make any changes to the thing `var` points to, copy it, or convert it. So you haven't done anything to the string `var` points to.

It's not clear what you're trying to do. But your code doesn't really do anything but convert a pointer value without changing or affecting the thing pointed to in any way.

When you convert a `LPCTSTR` (a long pointer to a const tchar string) to a `char*`, you get a `char*` that points to a `CTSTR` (a const tchar string). What use is that? What sense does that make?

Answer (score 1):

Most probaby `LPCTSTR` is `const wchar_t*`, so if you cast it to `char*` (which is Undefined Behaviour - as `var` could point to literal), the LSB byte (wchar_t under Visual Studio is 16bits) of `*var` is zero so it is treated as '\0' - which indicates end of string. So in the end you get only one char.

To convert `LPCTSTR` to `char*` you can use wsctombs for example, see here: [Convert const wchar_t* to const char*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8059724/convert-const-wchar-t-to-const-char).

Answer (score 1):

Here's an easy solution I found based on other answers given here.

```
char* GetChar(LPCTSTR var){
   char id[30];
   int i = 0;
   while (var[i] != '\0')
   {
      id[i] = (char)var[i];
      i++;
   }
   id[i] = '\0';
```

**UPDATE**
As mentioned in comments this is not a good way to solve this problem. But if someone has the same problem and cannot understand any other solution, this will help a bit. 
Therefore I won't remove this answer.

Comment: There are many reasons this code snippet is problematic. I would not recommend future readers use this solutions.

Comment: For one: there is a fixed size buffer that can be overrun in the loop. For another, the conversion can be quite problematic.  See the other answers to the current question for more; and see also this other question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5513718/1214731